# How to call a viewchild element's property in html?

Tags: angular, typescript

Usually, I define a ViewChild elemnt in component:

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Then I can call it in the html like this:

```
{{i+1+paginator.pageSize*paginator.pageIndex}}
```

But after angular's update I can't do it anymore , first it give me this error:

> "Property 'paginator' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

So I change my viewchild element with a non-null assertion operator

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
```

But then the HTML says I can't Cannot read properties of undefined

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageIndex')

How can I fix it?

================================================================
This is the whole html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dailyRecordSkeletrons">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index"> 
          {{i+1+paginator.pageSize*paginator.pageIndex}}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator (page)="onSearch()" [length]="rowCount" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

My old package.json:

```
{
  "name": "online-shop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "~13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "~13.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.9.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  }
}
```

And my current package.json

```
{
  "name": "timesheet",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.8",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.8",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.1.15",
    "ngx-spinner": "^13.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what versions the update include? , also - can u post your whole html

Comment: @gil updated information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign assertion operator to ***paginator*** variable it will give error because that ***paginator*** variable has also type **undefined** along with **MatPagitator**. Initially when the components load MatPaginator is not defined. So that is why it gives error.

So you must try

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator = new MatPaginator(new MatPaginatorIntl(), ChangeDetectorRef.prototype);
```

Instead of

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
```

Comment: It work but also give a error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'NaN'. Current value: '1'.

Comment: Should I just move the logic out of the template?

Comment: This article may help you https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/ in this case